# Filter out table's timestamps based on milliseconds

Tags: sql, mysql, database, google-bigquery

I have a table with good and bad timestamps in GCP Big Query.

A good timestamp:

1. That end with three or more zeros (000) in the milli second section.

`ex: 2023-10-10 07:42:39.603000 UTC.`

`ex: 2023-10-10 07:42:39.600000 UTC.`

`NOTE: 603000 ends with 000`.

2. That do not have the milli second section at all.

`ex: 2023-10-10 07:42:39 UTC.`

`ex: 2023-10-10 17:14:59 UTC.`

Now a Bad timestamp are those that end with non zero digits in the milli seconds section like so:

`ex: 2023-10-10 07:42:39.603567 UTC.`

`ex:  2023-10-10 07:42:39.600007 UTC.`

`NOTE: 603567 ends with 567`

I need to write a query that filters out all the bad timestamps and only has good timestamps.

I tried this but it filters out all the milli seconds in the timestamps.

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CAST(timestampcol AS STRING) LIKE '.%000' OR CAST(timestampcol  AS STRING) NOT LIKE '%.%'`

So I only see `ex: 2023-10-10 17:14:59` in all the rows.